# C++ Dekker's Algorithm not working as it should

Tags: c++, multiprocessing

This is really bugging me, I really can't see any mistake in this code.. It should do five times `cout<<"Process: "<<i+1<<", K.O. num: "<<k<<" ("<<m<<"/5)"<<endl;` with one process, than give turn to other, and constantly switch in between those two.
This code is going mostly random, and one process never finishes it's business.

And also, shared memory segment is not deleting when I use SIGINT..

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int Id; /* Segment Id */
int *TURN;
int *FLAG_I;
int *FLAG_J;

void get_out_of_critical(int i)
{
   if(i==0){
      *TURN=1;i=1;
      *FLAG_I=0;
   }
   else{
      *TURN=0;i=0;
      *FLAG_J=0;
   }

}

void get_in_critical(int i)
{
   if(i==0){
      *FLAG_I=1;
      while(*FLAG_J!=0){
           if(*TURN==1){
            *FLAG_I = 0;
            while(*TURN==1){}
         *FLAG_I=1;
         }
      }
   }
   else{
   *FLAG_J=1;
   while (*FLAG_I!=0){
         if(*TURN==0){
            *FLAG_J = 0;
            while(*TURN==0){}
         *FLAG_J=1;
         }
      }
   }

}

void process(int i)
{
   for(int k=1;k<=5;k++){
       get_in_critical(i);
       for(int m=1;m<=5;m++){
           cout<<"Process: "<<i+1<<", K.O. num: "<<k<<" ("<<m<<"/5)"<<endl;
                   //sleep(1);
      }
      get_out_of_critical(i);
   }
}


void del(int sig)
{
   /* free shared memory */
   (void) shmdt((char *) TURN);
   (void) shmdt((char *) FLAG_I);
   (void) shmdt((char *) FLAG_J);
   (void) shmctl(Id, IPC_RMID, NULL);
   exit(0);
}

int main()
{
   cout<<endl;
   /* allocating shared memory */
   Id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(int)*100, 0600);

   if (Id == -1)
      exit(1);

   TURN = (int *) shmat(Id, NULL, 0);
   *TURN = 0;
   FLAG_I = (int*) shmat(Id, NULL, 0);
   FLAG_J = (int*) shmat(Id, NULL, 0);
   *FLAG_I = 0;
   *FLAG_J = 0;
   sigset(SIGINT, del);// in case of signal interrupt, delete shared memory

   /* starting paralel processes */
   if (fork() == 0) {
      process(0);
      exit(0);
   }
   if (fork() == 0) {
      process(1);
      exit(0);
   }
   wait();
   wait();
   del(0);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The Wikipedia article on [Dekker's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dekker%27s_algorithm) explains what's wrong with your code:

> [..] Note however that the C/C++ "volatile" attribute only guarantees that the compiler generates code with the proper ordering; it does not include the necessary memory barriers to guarantee in-order execution of that code. C++11 atomic variables can be used to guarantee the appropriate ordering requirements [..]

So you have to use atomic variables and atomic operations for `TURN`, `FLAG_I` and `FLAG_J` in order to get this working. See also:

- [atomic_store](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_store)
- [atomic_load](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_load)

Comment: Thanks, but already solved it.. It was problem with memory allocating with `shmget`, had to put it for every variable for itself, and also added one `sleep(1);` in `get_out_of_critical()` to make enough time for other process to notice change in variable.